# Setting up Apache Virtual Hosts to point to a domain

Tags: ubuntu, dns, apache2

So I have Apache2 on Ubuntu (DigitalOcean) and I'm trying to set up an apache2 Virtual host to point to my domain , I have the virtual host file done (As shown below) , and I have all directorys done I own the domain I'm just not sure on how to point the domain to the apache2 or the other way around

I have tried pointing the domain to the server IP using DNS but it just means when you type in the address it converts it to the ip and displays the default virtual host (Not the one I created)

This is how my virtual hosts file looks

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName LeagueWeekly.co.uk
    ServerAdmin Jason@Wickedstudios.co.uk
    DocumentRoot /var/www/leagueweekly.co.uk/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated I'm sorry if this is in the wrong section.